# Javascript several Regular Expressions specific questions

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I check a regular expression that sometimes has white space in the middle, and sometimes doesn't? For example, how can I validate a credit card number based on just length, actual content doesn't matter.

Currently I'm doing

```js
    var pattern = /^\s*\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}\s*$/;
    var result = pattern.test(CC);
 if (result) {/* do thing */
```

This returns true if the number looks like XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX. It however, keeps return true if I do more XXXX's, so "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" is still returning true. I also need to figure out how to make XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX return true as well.

I also have another conundrum, this one may be simpler.

```js
{
    if(myAge >= 0 && myAge <= 118)
    {
        HTML.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else 
        HTML.innerHTML = "Invalid age";
}
```

If you set the input to myAge = 0 in the input box, and then back space so there is no number, it keeps returning true, is there a way to assert that when the box is empty that it will return to false???

Any help on any of the problems would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First Part:

Try this:

```
var pattern = /^\s*(?:\d{4}\s?){4}\s*$/;
```

Explanation:

```
^  : from the begining
\s*: spaces (0 or more)
(?:\d{4}\s?){4}: (?:...) means a group that will not be captured (will serve just for the repeatitions)
    \d{4}: 4 digits
    \s?  : a space (optional)
    {4}  : 4 times (4 of whatever in parentesis)
\s*: spaces (0 or more)
$  : the end
```

#### Second Part:

You have to check if `myAge` is a valid number (using `isNaN`) like this:

```
// if the myAge is not a number, less than 0 or greater than 118, then it's invalid
if(isNaN(myAge) || myAge < 0 || myAge > 118)
{
    HTML.innerHTML = "Invalid age";
}
else 
    HTML.innerHTML = "Valid age";
```

Comment: @Gwinert check the explanation!

Comment: @Gwinert as Keith said, you have to use numbers!

Comment: This helped for this problem, so thank you for that! If you have any ideas about the myAge one as well, that would be very appreciated! Thank you

Comment: @Gwinert I updated my answer: instead of capturing the groups, I used a non-capturing grouping (to optimize the regex)!

Comment: @Gwinert Check **Second part:** section in my answer! check the update on the regex as well!

Comment: Just a few more questions if I may, isNaN() isn't being recognized by my compiler, do I need to include anything? Also, how would I check a pattern for white space as well as a '$' Symbol? currently I'm at "/^(\s*|$)$/;"
Let me know, Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gwinert If you want the litteral `$` sign, then you have to escape it like this: `\$` so it wont be confused with the end of string `$` (check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/6647153) to see why).

Comment: @Gwinert and for the `isNaN` question, What browser are you executing this code on? As far as I know `isNaN` should be present on all modern browsers. Here is the docs for it on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you corectly you want this `/\b\d{4}\s*\d{4}\s*\d{4}\s*\d{4}\b/g`

Check if it is [Link](https://regex101.com/r/5BDiuO/1)